# Passing HTTP Headers to a Cloud Foundry App

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, serverless

I am trying to deploy a PHP application to a public Cloud Foundry app on IBM Cloud. This app uses an Authorization header with a Bearer token to authenticate API calls. However, this token is stripped off before it reaches my code which is preventing the API from working.

In the Cloud Foundry app's router logs, I can see that none of the original headers on the original request made to the app have been included. Is there a way to have the original headers included with these HTTP requests?

I can't seem to find anything that would enable this so far but wondering if anyone else has had this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization is a special header which can contain sensitive information. By default, Apache HTTPD which is what the PHP buildpack on Cloud Foundry will configure, is not going to pass Authorization along to scripts because this could leak sensitive information to the script.

You should be able to allow it by adding this setting: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#cgipassauth

If you add a `.htaccess` file to your app & put `CGIPassAuth On` in that file, that should make the `Authorization` header pass through. Alternatively, you can configure this way -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#engine-configurations

Alternatively, you can enable mod_openidc which is present out-of-the-box when using the PHP buildpack. It's a pretty straightforward way to enable OAuth2 based login. https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc

Ex: https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/static-site-oidc-example

Hope that helps!

Ref: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/190#issuecomment-433998851

Comment: The .htaccess method worked perfectly! Thank you so much!